# PLC Ladder logic - Problematic measurments of water flow in PLC

Tags: controls, plc, industrial

I've spent many hours and and a ton of paper sketching and I haven't been able to stumble upon anything to get me past this problem.

I can't figure out how to solve this task using PLC ladder language. PLC programme must compute actual flow of water. The gate is moving and the time of gate is set to 5 minutes. In this gate the impulses are counted (with wage for example - wage of 1 m^3). The overall time (the space where the gate can move) is set to 1 hour.

Gate time: for example 5 minutes Overall time: 1 hour Impulse is triggered by me.

Example if we trigger the I1 input - 3 times (one input have wage 1 m^3) in a gate of 5 minutes (5 minutes is 1/12 hour) so 3 * 1m^3 divided by (1/12)h = 36 m^3 / h It gave us actual water flow. I can only use TON timer and I've got 2 binary inputs.

Do you have any idea how to start this?

[image: Image showing the problem]

It's a logger I tried to base on, but now I don't know what to do next.

```
#include "MT-101.h"

IF FS1_fs MOVE 0, REG2 
IF FS1_fs MOVE RTC_Sec, REG2 
NE RTC_Sec, REG2, Q1 
IF NOT Q1 EXT
MOVE RTC_Sec, REG2 
IF NOT I1 EXT
TCPY XREG1, 511, XREG2 
MOVE AN1, XREG1
```